# Trying to access the parent of an XSSFShape results in NullPointerException

Tags: java, apache-poi

While trying to [traverse the inner contents of the ShapeContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760635/get-all-shapes-in-shapegroup), I wanted to differentiate between `XSSFPictures` which are children of `XSSFShapeGroup` and which are not by checking it's parent:

```java
private void traverseShapeContainer(ShapeContainer<XSSFShape> container) {
    for (XSSFShape shape : container) {
          // Other types of XSSFShapes have not been mentioned here.
          if (shape instanceof XSSFPicture) {
            XSSFPicture picture = (XSSFPicture) shape;
            System.out.println(shape.getParent() instanceof XSSFShapeGroup); // Always outputs false
            System.out.println(Objects.isNull(shape.getParent())); // Always outputs true
        } else if (shape instanceof XSSFShapeGroup) {
            XSSFShapeGroup shapeGroup = (XSSFShapeGroup) shape;
            // accessing inner contents of XSSFShapeGroup
            traverseShapeContainer(shapeGroup);
        }
    }
}
```

This was the same for every case whether an `XSSFPicture` was a child of a `XSSFShapeGroup` or not.

This seemed particularly strange after I performed these two tests to check for it's parent.

- **Test 1:** Checking whether the ShapeContainer is an instance of XSSFShapeGroup or not.

```java
System.out.println(Objects.isNull(container instanceof XSSFShapeGroup)); // Output: false
```

- **Test 2:** Looking for the parent tag after visiting the child node.

```java
if (shape instanceof XSSFPicture) {
   XSSFPicture picture = (XSSFPicture) shape;
   // "xdr:grpSp" is the tag for XSSFShapeGroup
   System.out.println(picture.getCTPicture().getDomNode().getParentNode().getNodeName()
                      .equals("xdr:grpSp")); // Output: true
}
```

This clearly shows that the parent does exist and also allows us to check for the parent in the process.

I haven't checked for other types of `XSSFShapes` such as `XSSFSimpleShape` or `XSSFConnector` yet. However, since they all inherit the same class,i.e, `XSSFShape` I guess the results wouldn't be much different.

So what might be wrong with `XSSFShape.getParent()` or is my perception of the problem incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of incompleteness of `apache poi` until now (May 2021, version `apache poi 5.0.0`). It it affects all shapes in a shape group.

`XSSFShape.getParent` simply returns the class member `XSSFShapeGroup parent` of the `XSSFShape`. But while parsing the `Office Open XML` drawing, apache poi simply does the following:

```
...
 } else if (obj instanceof CTGroupShape) {
  shape = new XSSFShapeGroup(this, (CTGroupShape) obj);
 }...
```

See https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_0_0/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFDrawing.java?view=markup#l619.

And constructor of `XSSFShapeGroup` simply does

```
protected XSSFShapeGroup(XSSFDrawing drawing, CTGroupShape ctGroup) {
 this.drawing = drawing;
 this.ctGroup = ctGroup;
}
```

See https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_0_0/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFShapeGroup.java?view=markup#l55.

So this lacks traversing all shapes in that group and set their parent to that shape group. So `parent` always will be `null`.

So either you get the parent using the low level classes, as you have shown already in your question. Or, better, you do checking the `container` in your method `traverseShapeContainer(ShapeContainer<XSSFShape> container)`, which **is** the parent container of all traversed shapes. You can get whether this is a `XSSFShapeGroup` or is the `XSSFDrawing`.

Like so:

```
...
 ... void traverseShapeContainer(ShapeContainer<XSSFShape> container) {
  for (XSSFShape shape : container) { 
   // possible:   XSSFConnector, XSSFGraphicFrame, XSSFPicture, XSSFShapeGroup, XSSFSimpleShape
   if (shape instanceof XSSFConnector) {
    XSSFConnector connector = (XSSFConnector)shape;
    System.out.println(connector);

   } else if (shape instanceof XSSFGraphicFrame) {
    XSSFGraphicFrame graphicFrame = (XSSFGraphicFrame)shape;
    System.out.println(graphicFrame);

   } else if (shape instanceof XSSFPicture) {
    XSSFPicture picture = (XSSFPicture)shape;
    System.out.println(picture);
    if (container instanceof XSSFDrawing) {
     System.out.println("Picture is in drawing directly.");
    } else if (container instanceof XSSFShapeGroup) {
     System.out.println("Picture is in shape group.");
     XSSFShapeGroup parent = (XSSFShapeGroup) container;
     System.out.println("Parent is " +  parent);
    }

   } else if (shape instanceof XSSFShapeGroup) { //we have a shape group
    XSSFShapeGroup shapeGroup = (XSSFShapeGroup)shape;
    System.out.println(shapeGroup);

    traverseShapeContainer(shapeGroup); // we now can sinply get the XSSFShapeGroup as ShapeContainer<XSSFShape>

   } else if (shape instanceof XSSFSimpleShape) {
    XSSFSimpleShape simpleShape = (XSSFSimpleShape)shape;
    System.out.println(simpleShape);

   }
  }

 }
...
```

Comment: May be notifying the maintainers would be a good idea too.

Comment: @dodobird: Do so ;-). I will not do this as of multiple reasons. But some members of apache poi developer community read and participate here too.